# Lua hook-like call AFTER line processing

Tags: debugging, lua, hook

Lua features hook call BEFORE every processed line. What I need is a call AFTER line is processed, so that I can check for encountered errors and so on. Is there a way to make such kind of call?

Otherwise things get a little bit confusing if error is encountered at the last line of the script. I don't get any feedback.

UPDATE #1
We want to catch both Lua errors and 'our' errors asserted via lua_error(*L) C interface, and Lua should throw correct debug info including the line number where the error occurred.

Using return hook we always get error line number -1, which is not what we want. Using any combination of pcall and any hook setup after lua_error(*L) we get either line number -1, or number of the next executed line, never a correct one.

SOLUTION#
We managed to make everything work. The thing was that Lua throws a real C exception after it detects an error, so some of our 'cleaning & finalizing' C code called from Lua operation did not execute, which messed up some flags and so on. The solution was to execute 'cleaning code' right before calling lua_error(...). This is correct and desired Lua behavior as we really want to stop executing the function once lua_error(...) is called, it was our mistake to expect any code would be executed after lua_error(...) call.

Tnx Paul Kulchenko, some of this behavior was found while trying to design a simple example script which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Before every processed line <=> before starting and then after every processed line but the last

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a *return* hook: it'll be called after the last line is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question with some addition info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure debug hook is the best solution for what you are trying to do (or you need to provide more details). If you just need to check for run-time errors, why use debug hooks at all if you can run your code with `pcall` and get an error message that points to the line number where the error happened (or use `xpcall`, which also allows you to get a stack trace)? You can combine this with `debug.getinfo(func, "L")` to get a table whose indexes are valid line numbers for the function.

Comment: We also want to use it for 'our' error asserted via lua_error(*L), and nothing seems to work correctly. I updated the question.

Comment: You'll need to come with a simple script that shows the issue.